How to efficiently handle multi-step course creation with React Context and file uploads?
I'm building a course creation feature for my LMS project. Instructors submit data via multiple forms, which I store in React Context. On the final step, I need to send the consolidated data to the backend for saving. The data includes nested objects and files (e.g., thumbnails, trailers, and lecture videos).
Here's the format of my data:
{
  "title": "Course Title",
  "sections": [
    {
      "sectionTitle": "Introduction",
      "lectures": [
        { "title": "Lecture 1", "video": File },
        { "title": "Lecture 2", "video": File }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "thumbnail": File,
  "trailer": File
}

I'm currently using React Context to manage state and FormData to send data, but I'm unsure how to handle the following:

Structuring API calls for efficient file uploads.
Organizing the backend logic to process this nested data format.
Optimizing the workflow to avoid redundant API calls.

I'm looking for guidance on structuring the API calls and backend logic to handle this complex course creation workflow, including file uploads and nested data.
